# Applet isShowing() vs Frame isShowing()

Tags: java, applet, awt, frame

I'm trying to replicate my code originally made extending the Applet class.
but the code below is always true for a `Frame`. I understand that `isShowing()` will always return true if the Frame `isVisible()` is also true. Unless the `setVisible()` is explicitly set to false, `isShowing()` will return true.

My goal is to pause a daemon thread from looping when the application Frame is minimized.

```
public class Screen extends Applet{

@Override
public void init() {

    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void componentShown(ComponentEvent e) {
            //do stuff

        }

        @Override
        public void componentHidden(ComponentEvent e) {
            //Stop doing stuff
        }       
    });
}
```

Implement suggestion (Boris Pavlović)

```
public class Screen extends Frame implements Runnable{

private boolean runL;
private Thread thread;

public Screen() {
    setSize(256,256);
    setVisible(true);

    addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            runL = true;
            starThread();
        }

        @Override
        public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e) {
            runL = false;
        }

    });

}


@Override
public void run() {
    while(runL){System.out.println("showing");}
}

private void starThread(){
    if(thread == null){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    } else if(!thread.isAlive()){
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the tutorial on "[How to Use Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html)". `WindowsAdapter` allows for overriding different state transitions which may be used to start/stop the computation.

Answer (score 0):

> My goal is to pause a daemon thread from looping when the application Frame is minimized.

Add a `WindowListener` and stop the calculation on [`windowIconified(WindowEvent)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html#windowIconified%28java.awt.event.WindowEvent%29).